# Android Drawable folders aren't detected?

Tags: android, drawable, image-scaling

How do the drawable folders work nowadays?

I used to be able to just add folders named drawable-mdpi and such to get image resources, but this feature has seemingly disappeared. Image assets doesn't allow me to add image assets that aren't icons without messing them up and manually adding the drawable folders I need doesn't work any more as android can no longer find the resources.

How does android look for drawables now and how can I add prescaled images to my projects manually?

Comment: This happened to me once, and I had to make a new project and move everything over to fix it. There is probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: Right now my solution is supporting the single device this app will run on for the foreseeable future haha. It's not very future proof and personally I can't stand not knowing something so seemingly basic yet confusing since the internet is filled with advice about older and transitional versions. Even the official docs seem to say "just add drawable folders"

Comment: yea, it was pretty frustrating, someone on here will likely know though.